# How is the root index.html generated?

Tags: hexo

I am building a blog site with Hexo, with my own template and layouts, and I do not understand how the root `index.html` is supposed to be built. I will have one home page (the `index.html` above) and posts.

My idea was that I would have:

**an `index.html` file in `sources`** which would have a specific layout in the frontmatter (`layout: home`) and the unique content of the page (say, `this is the content of the home page`)

```
---
title: the home page
layout: home
---
this is the content of the home page
```

**a `home.esj` file in `themes/mytheme/layouts`** which would have the header and footer common to all pages (the HTML declaration, a navbar and a footer)

```
<%- partial('header') %>
<%- partial('nav') %>
<%- page.content %>
<%- partial('footer') %>
```

Upon running the build, I expected `index.html` to be merged with `home.esj` and create a `public/index.html` page with the HTML declaration, a navbar, `this is the content of the home page` and a footer. I got an empty file.

So maybe `.html` is not processed? I renamed to `index.md`, and `index.html` was created in `public` -- still empty.

The build process is showing

```
WARN  No layout: archives/index.html
WARN  No layout: archives/2018/index.html
WARN  No layout: archives/2018/02/index.html
WARN  No layout: tags/tech/index.html
WARN  No layout: index.html
INFO  Generated: index.html
```

It would then seem that the layout is not taken into account?

**However:**

- I have a specific layout for posts called `mypost.esj` (so not the standard naming). The default layout is set to `nonexistinglayout`. Posts which do not explicitely state `layout: mypost` in the frontmatter are empty, and the one which do - with the right customized content (of the layout and the post itself)
- if I remove `sources/index.*` and create a `themes/mytheme/layouts/index.esj` file which holds the partials and the expected content of the page (`this is the content of the home page`), I get a `public/index.html` file which is the one I want.

How exactly is `index.html` handled by Hexo?

Comment: By default, Hexo expectes the index HTML to be a list of all your posts. http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/03/Create-an-Hexo-Theme-Part-1-Index/